# How to get the user_id field in Auth0 Hooks?

Tags: auth0, openid-connect

I'm trying out some of the new Hooks features in Auth0, specifically the post-registration hook.  I was hoping to use the `user_id` profile field, i.e. `provider|id` as mentioned [here](https://community.auth0.com/questions/6013/storing-the-user-id-in-a-local-database) so we could create a user record on our application side.  We would assign UUIDs to our users, but each would have a unique key from Auth0.

A sample of the hook looks like this - I am exporting the entire set of data available to me:

```
module.exports = function (user, context, cb) {
  var request = require('request');
  request({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: 'https://requestb.in/1ejaxvz1',
    body: {
     "id": user.id,
     "user": user,
     "context": context
    },
    json: true
  },
  function(error, response, body) { 
    console.log(user);
    console.log(context);
    cb(error, response) 
  });
};
```

However, while this gives me the user's base ID, it does not appear that information about the full `user_id` or anything about the `provider` is available to the hook.  In other words, rather than giving me the full id that looks like `provider|12345678`, I only get the `12345678`.  When I get the jwt from Auth0, the `sub` value is returned as `provider|12345678`.

So my question has 2 parts:
1) Is this full user ID intentionally left out of hooks for a reason or is this a design oversight?  This feature is still in beta at the time of writing this.

2) Without the full user ID `provider|12345678` I can't do an exact match on the `sub` value in the jwt.  But, I *could* attempt to partial-match by dropping the `provider`.  I'm not clear on whether this is a valid practice though.  I suspect it's not, but this is tricky to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Post-registration hook](https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/extensibility-points/post-user-registration) is only run on Database signups and the `user_id` format will always be prefixed with `auth0|` when entered into the Database. This might change in the future however.

> 1) Is this full user ID intentionally left out of hooks for a reason or is this a design oversight? This feature is still in beta at the time of writing this.

This would be by design but I do agree that the better approach would be to expose the full `user_id` in hooks including the provider as well.

> 2) Without the full user ID provider|12345678 I can't do an exact match on the sub value in the jwt. But, I could attempt to partial-match by dropping the provider. I'm not clear on whether this is a valid practice though. I suspect it's not, but this is tricky to test.

Yes, you would have to prefix the `user_id` with `auth0|` to get the exact match. Again this is not the best practice but Hooks is still beta.

Comment: Your workaround sounds good to me.  Since post-reg hooks are for database signups only it sounds like hard-coding `auth0` is quite safe.  That was the thing I was most worried about.  Thanks!